# Java AWT : Will applet run without main(), init(), start(), paint()

Tags: java, applet, awt, mouselistener

I'm learning AWT and plan to learn Swing later.

I've found the following code for an applet, from what I know applets will start running when the following methods are present: main(), init(), start(), paint()...

The applets just increases it's width and length dimension each time the mouse is clicked:

In this code none of the above is present, how is the ResizeMe method called? how is the addmouselistener called if the resize methid is not called??
edit: btw the code works

```
// Resizing output to fit the current size of a window.
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*
  <applet code="ResizeMe" width=200 height=200>
  </applet>
 */

public class ResizeMe extends Applet {
  final int inc = 25;
  int max = 500;
  int min = 200;
  Dimension d;

  public ResizeMe() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        int w = (d.width + inc) > max?min :(d.width + inc);
        int h = (d.height + inc) > max?min :(d.height + inc);
        setSize(new Dimension(w, h));
      }
    });
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    d = getSize();

    g.drawLine(0, 0, d.width-1, d.height-1);
    g.drawLine(0, d.height-1, d.width-1, 0);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, d.width-1, d.height-1);
  }
}
```

Thanks, Luther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResizeMe()` is the constructor. Therefore it is called on class creation and therefore, your mouse listener is added. `paint()` is called by the GUI event handling thread.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `main` is for desktop applications. The following methods are called at specific moment in the life cycle of an applet, and allow to do something specific for that life cycle.

- init - initially
- start - when the HTML page (re)starts
- stop - when one leaves the HTML page
- destroy - when the applet is unloaded

Furthermore the component part of AWT is really obsolete; only java.awt.Color, Font and such are in use, Applet, Button and others one will not find easily.

So I would advise to immediately switch to swing.

---

**AWT** has every pure Java component peered with a native code (operating system) component. So a Button is on Windows a real Windows Button. So there is a separate AWT implementation for Windows, Mac and Linux.

**Swing** does all itself, and has several Look-and-Feels (themes/skins). The System Look-and-Feek emulates the current operating system as near as feasible.
Swings advantage is its high configurability, like on a JLabel minimizing the distance between icon and text, or being able to use HTML for every text component, by just writing `"<html><b>Boldly</b> go, ..."`.

Swing was a newer effort.

Comment: I thought that since Swing is a superset of AWT, learning first AWT would have given me a better understanding of SWING. Don't you agree?

Comment: Elaborated the answer. Swing was built around AWT, but especially the GUI components were no longer used; the components became "light weight" meaning that having many components no longer implied heavy resource usage and switching between JVM code and native code.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Applet class provides default implementations for the `init`, `start` and `paint` methods (see [java.applet.Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/applet/Applet.html)).  The ResizeMe class inherits from `java.applet.Applet` and thus inherits all the methods from the Applet class (for more on inheritance, see [subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)).

Applets do not require `main` methods since it is embedded inside another application.

The `ResizeMe()` method is a constructor.  It gets called automatically when the ResizeMe class is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

ResizeMe is extending Applet, which means that it is inheriting all of the methods that Applet has.  Take a look at the [Docs for Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) to see which methods it contains, and which ones it inherits from its parents.

Also, there really is no reason to learn AWT and then Swing.